# Search for Images from Omnibox directly in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, images, search, address-bar

Is there anyway to configure Google Chrome's Omnibox to search directly for Images instead of default Web search?

Relatively any possibilities for making news search and rest types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Go to [Google images](https://www.google.com/imghp)
2. Right-click on the search field and click `Add search engine`
   A new window will popup

   [image]
3. Choose your desired keyword i.e. `image`
4. Don't change the URL parameter
5. Click in your omnibar and type `image test`

This way your omnibar searches for images and displays Googles image search page

**Note:** The described method can be used for allmost every search engine i.e. Google News

Comment: Yeap; Can be useful for almost any search box.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you @nixda, and I love the fact that your answer from 2013 is still relevant in late 2015 :)

Comment: `Add search engine` seems to be no longer available in 2019.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate in 2019 due to Chrome updates.  The option to add search engine is no longer in the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

`Chrome > Preferences > Manage search engines`

For Google Image Search, use the query URL:

`https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbm=isch&q=%s`

[image: image search preferences]

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  As of October 2019, this is the only answer that works in modern versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the same thing, but if you right click in most search engine fields you want to use in the omnibox you can select "Add as Search Engine" from the context menu.